# Put every occurrence of a string into html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For putting `p` string into `div` we can use jquery's wrap() function like this:

```
 $('p').wrap("<div></div>");
```

Is there a way to enclose every occurrence of the string 'p' in a html tag?

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>

        bla bla bla Hello world other words and etc and again Hello world

    </body>
</html>
```

In this html document there are two "Hello world", how can I put they in `p` tag?

The needed html result must be:

```
bla bla bla `<p>Hello world</p>` other words and etc and again `<p>Hello world</p>`
```

Comment: I'm having a really hard time understanding what you want to happen. Maybe you could show us some example HTML of what the desired results you want would appear like.

Comment: ok, I will update my question

Comment: Do you want the input `<body>foo Hello, World bar Hello, World baz</body>` to map to the output `<body>foo <p>Hello, World</p> bar <p>Hello, World</p> baz</body>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your example.. you can do it like this using regex

```
$('body').html(function(i,v){
  return v.replace(/Hello world/g,'<p>Hello world</p>');
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UfNx3/)

Or using split

```
$('body').html(function(i,v){
  return v.split('Hello world').join('<p>Hello world</p>');
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/N6vPv/)

Comment: Regular expression operations on HTML can be problematic.  If your replacement text contains double quotes, and whatever you want to wrap also appears inside attributes, then you'll end up mangling the HTML in bad ways.  For example, `v = '<div title="Hello, World"> Hello, World</div>'` and replacing with `<p class="foo">$&</p>` will lead to ugliness.

Answer (score 1):

from what I understand you want to put Hello World in that paragraph element. there's two ways you can do this.

Either

```
$('<p>Hello World</p>').wrap("<div></div>");
```

or

```
$('p').wrap("<div></div>").text('Hello World');
```

Comment: Not this, Sorry for my english,  please see update in my question

Answer (score 1):

You can find all text nodes thus,

```
function forEachTextNode(f, node) {
  if (node.nodeType === 3) {
    f(node);
  } else {
    for (var child = node.firstChild, next; child; child = next) {
      next = child.nextSibling;  // Grab next early in case f mutates the DOM.
      forEachTextNode(f, child);
    }
  }
}
```

then split using [`Text.splitText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Text.splitText) to break out the words you want:

```
function forEachSubstring(f, text, textNode) {
  var i = textNode.nodeValue.indexOf(text);
  if (i >= 0) {
    // Split before the words we want to operate on.
    textNode.splitText(i);
    var substringNode = textNode.nextSibling;
    // Split after the words we want to operate on.
    substringNode.splitText(text.length);
    var rest = substringNode.nextSibling;
    // Operate on the substring.
    f(substringNode);
    // Recurse to look for more occurrences of text.
    forEachSubstring(f, text, rest);
  }
}
```

and then tie them together thus:

```
function wrapInParagraph(node) {
  var wrapper = node.ownerDocument.createElement('p');
  node.parentNode.replaceChild(wrapper, node);
  wrapper.appendChild(node);
}

forEachTextNode(
    function (tn) { forEachSubstring(wrapInParagraph, "Hello, World", tn); },
    document.body);
```